# Remove Server Header from NGINX

Tags: docker, nginx

I'm having some troubles removing the Server Header completely.

> **Response Headers:** server: nginx/1.19.7

I have NGINX running inside a docker container

```
FROM nginx:alpine

RUN apk --no-cache add curl
COPY nginx/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY --from=builder /data/build/ /usr/share/nginx/html/
```

I used `server_tokens off;` but this only removed the version from the header

> **Response Headers:** server: nginx

So I tried  `more_clear_headers Server;` but I get an error.

> [emerg] 1#1: unknown directive "more_clear_headers" in
> /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:6

Any help?

Comment: @super no, this is for docker usage

Comment: I think [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/214242/can-i-hide-all-server-os-info) might help. to see if you placed this in the right context can you please send your configuration files for Nginx?

Comment: @TiagoSilva Doesn't make any difference if it's for docker or not. Nginx works the same way no matter how/where you run it.